# Fatal Error when using Service from vendor module in Zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have a ZF2 application with 1 module and I am trying to use a class from another module called "CommonRestClient" located in the "vendor" directory.

The directory structure of this "vendor" directory is as under:

```
vendor
-->CommonRestClient
---->config
------>module.config.php
-->src
---->CommonRestClient
------->Service
--------->CommonRestClient.php
-->Module.php
```

> ```
> vendor\CommonRestClient\config\module.config.php
> ================================================
> <?php
> return array();
> ?>
>
> vendor\src\Module.php
> ======================
> <?php
>
> namespace CommonRestClient;
>
> use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
> use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
>
> use Zend\Http\Client as HttpClient;
> use CommonRestClient\Service\CommonRestClient as CommonRestClient;
>
> class Module
> {
>     public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
>     {
>         $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
>         $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
>         $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
>     }
>
>     public function getConfig()
>     {
>         return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
>     }
>
>     public function getAutoloaderConfig()
>     {
>         return array(
>             'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
>                 'namespaces' => array(
>                     __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
>                 ),
>             ),
>         );
>     }
>
>     public function getServiceConfig()
>     {
>         return array(
>             'factories' => array(
>                 'CommonRestClient\Service\CommonRestClient' => function($sm) {
>                     $httpClient = $sm->get('HttpClient');
>                     $httpRestJsonClient = new CommonRestClient($httpClient);
>                     return $httpRestJsonClient;
>                 },
>                 'HttpClient' => function($sm) {
>                     $httpClient = new HttpClient();
>                     $httpClient->setAdapter('Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl');
>                     return $httpClient;
>                 },
>             ),
>         );
>     }
> }
>
> vendor\src\CommonRestClient\Service\CommonRestClient.php
> =========================================================
> <?php
>
> namespace CommonRestClient\Service;
>
> use Zend\Http\Client as HttpClient;
> use Zend\Http\Request;
> use Zend\Stdlib\Parameters;
>
> class CommonRestClient
> {
>     protected $httpClient;
>
>     public function __construct(HttpClient $httpClient)
>     {
>         $this->httpClient = $httpClient;
>     }
>
>     public function get($url)
>     {
>         return $this->dispatchRequestAndDecodeResponse($url, "GET");
>     }
>
>     public function post($url, $data)
>     {
>         return $this->dispatchRequestAndDecodeResponse($url, "POST", $data);
>     }
>
>     public function put($url, $data)
>     {
>         return $this->dispatchRequestAndDecodeResponse($url, "PUT", $data);
>     }
>
>     public function delete($url)
>     {
>         return $this->dispatchRequestAndDecodeResponse($url, "DELETE");
>     }
>
>     protected function dispatchRequestAndDecodeResponse($url, $method, $data = null)
>     {
>         $request = new Request();
>         $request->getHeaders()->addHeaders(array(
>             'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
>         ));
>         $request->setUri($url);
>         $request->setMethod($method);
>
>         if ($data){
>             $request->setPost(new Parameters($data));
>         }
>
>         $response = $this->httpClient->dispatch($request);
>         # should interogate response status, throwing appropiate exceptions for error codes
>         return json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
>     }
> }
> ```

So, in the main application module, I am trying to use the above class in a Model file, which looks like this:

> ```
> <?php
>
> namespace MyApplication\Model;
>
> use CommonRestClient\Service\CommonRestClient as CommonRestClient;
>
> class Users
> {    
>     protected $commonRestClient;
>
>     public function __construct(CommonRestClient $commonRestClient)
>     {
>         $this->commonRestClient = $commonRestClient;
>     }
>
>     public function getListOfUsers()
>     {
>         $url = 'http://xyz.google.com/getusers';
>         $jsonResponse = $this->commonRestClient->get($url);
>         return $jsonResponse;
>     }
> }
> ```

I have configured MyApplication's application.config.php to use the "CommonRestClient" module.

The error I am recieving is:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to
>   MyApplication\Model\Users::__construct() must be an instance of
>   CommonRestClient\Service\CommonRestClient, none given, called in
>   C:\Users\Public\myapp\myapplication\module\MyApplication\src\MyApplication\Controller\UsersController.php
>   on line 27 and defined in
>   C:\Users\Public\myapp\myapplication\module\MyApplication\src\MyApplication\Model\Users.php
>   on line 23

Can any one help me with what I could be missing here?

Thanks

Comment: What is line 27 of the users controller?

Comment: $users = new Users(); 
is the line 27 in users controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the constructor you defined for your `Users` class you specified a required argument of `CommonRestClient` which you are not supplying when creating the instance from your controller, so that's why you are getting the error.

You can either supply the argument yourself:

```
$users = new Users($this->getServiceLocator()->get('CommonRestClient\Service\CommonRestClient'));
```

or tell ZF how to do that using a factory:

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Users' => function($sm) {
                $commonRestClient = $sm->get('CommonRestClient\Service\CommonRestClient');
                $users = new Users($commonRestClient);
                return $users;
            },
        ),
    );
}
```

and then use the service locator to create the instance for you:

```
$users = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Users');
```